# Link directly to a file from a block

Tags: 7, files, navigation

I have a full-HTML block and I want to put a link to a file into it that varies with the sitepath. I saw somewhere something about putting public:// instead of http:// to route to `sites/default/files`, but it doesn't seem to work from block content at least (is that only in php?)

So I have a block with `<img src="public://img/screenshot.png"/>` in the content and nothing is happening. Any ideas how to make this work? I don't to use image module or anything like that yet.. just a link to a file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to use [file_create_url()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!file.inc/function/file_create_url/7) and the 'PHP code' format (comes with the core 'PHP filter' module) for this to work:

```
<img src="<?php print file_create_url('public://img/screenshot.png'); ?>"/>
```

If possible I would suggest adding it inside the block's template file instead though.

Comment: so there's no way without having PHP enabled? :/

Comment: Well, HTML code is static so you can't use it to create a dynamic link. Like I mentioned you could maybe add this code snippet directly inside the block template file though. If the sites have a similar path structure then you could use a relative url like '/sites/default/files/img/screenshot.png' also.

Comment: I know html code is static, but a lot of systems (like wordpress) have shortcodes so that you can do this sort of thing without having to turn on PHP scripting for a content area (which is potentially dangerous)